# Traduction de "Before the world was made", de Yeats

Tags: traduction, poésie

Il existe une poésie de [Yeats](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Butler_Yeats) dont le titre est *Before the world was made*. Yves Bonnefoy, qu'on ne présente plus, l'a traduit dans le recueil [Quarante-cinq poèmes](http://livre.fnac.com/a263943/Yves-Bonnefoy-Quarante-cinq-poemes-La-Resurrection) par *Avant qu'il n'y ait le monde*.

Cela m'embête beaucoup, car *il n'y ait* ne passe pas du tout à l'oral  et je voudrais présenter ce poème oralement. C'est d'autant plus ennuyeux que l'expression est employée deux fois dans le poème.

Serait-il possible, selon vous, sans insulter l'auteur, de traduire par *Avant qu'il y ait le monde* ? (à lire l'anglais je ne comprends pas pourquoi Bonnefoy — malgré tout le respect que j'ai pour lui — a mis *n'*).

Voici les autres apparitions :

> No vanity displayed :
>   I'm looking for the face I had
>   Before the world was made.

… que Bonnefoy a traduit par :

> Nulle vanité ! Je recherche
>   Le visage qui fut le mien
>   Avant qu'il n'y ait le monde.

Et :

> I'd have him love the thing that was
>   Before the world was made

par :

> Je le veux aimant ce qui fut
>   Avant qu'il n'y ait le monde.

Ou alors auriez vous des suggestions complètement différentes ?

Comment: En fait, je trouve humblement que la traduction est de très grande qualité. Je ne pourrais jamais oser suggérer autre chose, car ce serait moins bon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il s'agit ici de l'emploi explétif de *ne*. 
 Au sujet de cet emploi voir la [Banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2467) de l'Office québécois de la langue française et le [Centre de communication écrite de l'Université de Montréal](http://www.cce.umontreal.ca/observations/ne.htm), qui mentionne son emploi avec « avant que ».

Grevisse signale que l'usage du « ne explétif » dans les subordonnées (ce qui est le cas ici), non obligatoire et qui tend à disparaître, se trouve à l'écrit dans le registre littéraire. Et c'est précisément pour rendre la langue de Yeats, littéraire s'il en fût, que Bonnefoy conserve l'usage du ne explétif dans une tournure elle-même littéraire. Le rôle du traducteur n'est pas de traduire mot à mot mais de traduire une atmosphère tout en gardant le sens. Traduire Yeats exige l'usage de tournures littéraires, voir désuètes, et certainement pas une langue de tous les jours.

Une autre raison, ou une raison supplémentaire au choix du traducteur d'introduire ce ne explétif, serait une question de diction, car la poésie est avant tout faite pour être dite.
Le ne explétif entraîne plus facilement, de par son image littéraire, une diction elle aussi littéraire ; il amène à ralentir le rythme de la parole, et à faire la distinction entre le son /i/ dans le son /j/ qui seraient spontanément (mais bien sûr pas obligatoirement) assimilés dans le discours normal non littéraire :

- sur deux syllabes  |qu'il|y ait| *[kilje]*
- sur trois syllabes |qu'il|y|ait| *[kilije]*

L'introduction du son consonne /n/ supplémentaire rend la diction |qu'il|n'y|ait| *[kilnije]* plus spontanée.

On remarquera le choix du traducteur de faire trois vers de huit syllabes (si *recherche* reste dit sur deux syllabe et pas trois).

Comment: La présence du *ne* ne change rien au nombre de syllables. */kil.nje/* (peut-être *ɲe* je ne sais pas les distinguer) ou */kil.ni.je/*.

Comment: Je trouve votre réponse très bonne, mais je reste un peu sur ma faim : de "n'y" à "y" le nombre de syllabes reste le même, non ? Et comment gérez vous à l'oral le "n'y ait" sans aller à "nier" ? (vous dites "niè" au lieu de "nié" ?... comme déssuétission, c'est gagné ! ). Mais vous m'avez donné l'explication, et l'importance, du n', qui était bien mystérieux pour moi.

Comment: @Istao: j'ai modifié l'obligatoire (subjectif!) en "plus facile" (j'aurais pu dire logique) - et le compte se fait sur l'assimilation du son /i/ dans le son /j/.  J'espère que c'est plus clair.

Comment: (+1) Très bonne réponse, notamment à propos du bien-fondé (ici) de tournures littéraires ou désuètes.

Answer (score 3):

Il y a une expression française :
**"Avant que le monde soit monde"**

Ce n'est pas très utilisé oralement mais c'est une formule assez poétique qui convient bien dans ce cas.

Answer (score 2):

Le poème est sublime. Et en l'occurrence même si la traduction proposée (avec le fameux *n'* qui te gêne) est a priori excellente, je ne trouve pas ton questionnement hors de propos, on pourrait imaginer ou souhaiter d'autres traductions. Je me permets de suggérer quelques pistes à envisager, plus ou moins libres, ne serait-ce que pour faire avancer tes recherches ou suggérer d'autres associations.

> Avant que fut le monde
>
> Avant que soit le monde
>
> Avant que le monde soit
>
> Avant la fection du monde (?!)
>
> Avant le fait du monde
>
> Avant que le monde soit monde
>
> Dans l'avant du monde
>
> Au deça du monde
>
> Avant que le monde soit fait *(© Istao 2014)*

Comment: Et pourquoi pas "Avant que le monde soit fait" ? Pourquoi Bonnefoy a-t-il traduit le "made" qui, de mes lointains souvenirs, se rapporte à "faire", en une expression qui se rapporte à une suite d'état ? Ou alors c'est une des acceptations de "made" ?

Comment: @Istao Ta proposition me semble excellente également. Avec ta permission, je la rajoute à la liste.

Comment: Curieusement, il est commun de *refaire le monde* mais pas du tout de *faire le monde*.

Answer (score 1):

L'auteur a fait ses choix. 
Pour *passer* la frontière des langues, rien ne vous empêche de donner une autre « vision », une autre oralité.
La « licence poétique » renvoie à l'origine du sens par-delà le mot écrit, pour migrer vers le mot « chanté ».

Bien sûr il faudra préciser ce que vous avez modifié dans la traduction de l'auteur, mais reprendre tout le texte est un enjeu passionnant pour approfondir sa connaissance des mots la signification de leur place dans le phrasé, les nuances qui « explosent » les certitudes illusoires…  en toute liberté, hors des conventions :

> No vanity displayed :
>   I'm looking for the face
>   I had  Before the world was made.
>
> Rien de vain n'apparaît,
>   Je recherche mon visage
>   D'avant la naissance du monde

Puis

> I'd have him love the thing that was
>   Before the world was made.
>
> Je le ferai aimer ce qui était
>   Avant la naissance du monde

Ou, si le nombre de pieds compte :

> Il aimera ce qui était
>   Avant que le monde naisse

Answer (score -1):

Il signifie "avant la création du monde"!

Comment: Mouais, ça traduit bien le sens littéral mais ça manque de poésie.